# Change pandas dataframe to flat format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 100 columns with the following format:

```
DateTime    2008_11  2008_12
10/22/2008  2        NaN
10/23/2008  1        NaN
10/24/2008  3        4
10/27/2008  4        6
10/28/2008  NaN      5
```

I want to create the following flat file:

```
DateTime    Name      Value
10/22/2008  2008_11   2
10/23/2008  2008_11   1
10/24/2008  2008_11   3
10/27/2008  2008_11   4
10/28/2008  2008_11   NaN
10/22/2008  2008_12   NaN
10/23/2008  2008_12   NaN
10/24/2008  2008_12   4
10/27/2008  2008_12   6
10/28/2008  2008_12   5
```

I have no idea how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pandas.melt`, and set the column that maintains (the `DateTime` here) as the `id_vars`, all the columns by default will be gathered in the long format with the header in one column, values in another; You can use `var_name` and `value_name` to rename the two columns respectively:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars='DateTime', var_name='name')

      DateTime    name  value
0   10/22/2008  2008_11 2.0
1   10/23/2008  2008_11 1.0
2   10/24/2008  2008_11 3.0
3   10/27/2008  2008_11 4.0
4   10/28/2008  2008_11 NaN
5   10/22/2008  2008_12 NaN
6   10/23/2008  2008_12 NaN
7   10/24/2008  2008_12 4.0
8   10/27/2008  2008_12 6.0
9   10/28/2008  2008_12 5.0
```

Comment: Great answer as usual (-:

Answer (score 2):

By using `stack`

```
df.set_index('DateTime').stack(dropna=False).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Name',0:'Value'})
Out[162]: 
     DateTime     Name  Value
0  10/22/2008  2008_11    2.0
1  10/22/2008  2008_12    NaN
2  10/23/2008  2008_11    1.0
3  10/23/2008  2008_12    NaN
4  10/24/2008  2008_11    3.0
5  10/24/2008  2008_12    4.0
6  10/27/2008  2008_11    4.0
7  10/27/2008  2008_12    6.0
8  10/28/2008  2008_11    NaN
9  10/28/2008  2008_12    5.0
```

As piRSquared's suggestion

```
df.set_index('DateTime').rename_axis('Name', 1).stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='Value')
```

Comment: I like this modification `df.set_index('DateTime').rename_axis('Name', 1).stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='Value')`